# Django: Trying to select random result, but get Object has no len() error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am building a Django-Rest API that returns a random object from a queryset

```
  class AdViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AdSerializer
    queryset = Ad.objects.none()

    def get_queryset(self):
      if 'verify' in self.request.GET:
          # Return random object
          random_ad = Ad.objects.filter(verified=False).order_by('?').first()
          # return random_ad
          return random_ad

      return Ad.objects.all().order_by('-pk')
```

But this code returns the `object of type 'Ad' has no len()` error.

Removing the `.first()` command causes the API to return a queryset, so I know it is getting results. But I need a single (random) instance.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's expecting a QuerySet containing the result. By using `first()`, you are returning one item from the list of results.

Instead of using `first()`, try slicing the queryset:

```
random_ad = Ad.objects.filter(verified=False).order_by('?')[:1]
```

Comment: Ah, I failed to consider that. Thanks for you help!